# Time.now.to_date is returning tomorrow, not today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, heroku, time

I have a rails app on Heroku and I thought I had the time zone configured correctly (USA Central Standard Time). I expect the following to return today's date:

```
Time.now.to_date
```

But instead it's returning tomorrow's date if it's after 7pm my time. What's the best way to get today's date within the time zone you configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Date.current](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current) which respects the given time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Check `ENV['TZ']` which should be `US/Central` or `America/Chicago` or similar for you. An empty string means UTC. Nil means the system setting is used, which you can get by:

`$ readlink /etc/localtime`

Check `Time.now.zone` which should be `CST` or `CDT` depending on season.

If TZ (or the `/etc/localtime` symlink) is set correctly, I think Time and Date should both give you what you expect. But I am not totally sure, I challenge everyone stumbling upon this note to run this code at any location in the world at any time of any day you happen to be:

`$ ruby -r time -e 'puts ENV["TZ"]+" "+Time.now.iso8601+" "+(Date.today == Time.now.to_date).to_s'`

for me now it says:

`Europe/Budapest 2020-04-21T22:12:23+02:00 true`

I expect the end of the line to always be true, but the documentation of Date is pretty obscure to me. Let's see in practice.

In case you care I just found out I can use the following bash scriptlet to convert my location to a time zone name:

`$ tzselect -c +47.6418+19.154 -n 1 <<<$'1\n1' 2>/dev/null`

resulting in

`Europe/Budapest`